# How to do a fresh install of mysql on mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm trying to install mysql again because I've set it up with a password and I forgot it. So when I try to connect to the monitor, I always get error 1045 access denied.

How can I completely remove mysql or is there a way that I can remove the password?

Thanks!

Comment: You should try to reset the password instead, in case you have databases and tables, check this out https://gist.github.com/zubaer-ahammed/c81c9a0e37adc1cb9a6cdc61c4190f52

Comment: It worked, thanks!
But when I try to connect to my DB through sequel pro, i get this error: MySQL said: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found

Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: I just came across this with PostgreSQL, in my case, I did upgrade mac home brew postgres, and I forgot to run the upgrade script, maybe in your case its related to using legacy password module for MySQL, try to check if you did run the upgrade script for MySQL.